# Hystrix Javanica : Call always returning result from fallback method.(java web app without spring)

Tags: hystrix

I am trying to integrate Hystrix javanica into my existing java EJB web application and facing 2 issues with running it.

1. When I try to invoke following service it always returns response from fallback method and I see that the Throwable object in fallback method has "com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixTimeoutException" exception.
2. Each time this service is triggered, HystrixCommad and fallback methods are called multiple times around 50 times.

Can anyone suggest me with any inputs? Am I missing any configuration?

I am including following libraries in my project.
[project libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWujI.png)

I have setup my aspect file as follows:

```
<aspectj>
 <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo"></weaver>
 <aspects>
    <aspect name="com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect"/>
 </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Here is my config.properties file in META-INF/config.properties

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
```

Here is my rest service file

```
@Path("/hystrix")
public class HystrixService {

 @GET
 @Path("clusterName")
 @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
 public Response getClusterName(@QueryParam("id") int id) {
    ClusterCmdBean clusterCmdBean = new ClusterCmdBean();
    String result = clusterCmdBean.getClusterNameForId(id);
    return Response.ok(result).build();
 }
}
```

Here is my bean class

```
public class ClusterCmdBean {

 @HystrixCommand(groupKey = "ClusterCmdBeanGroup", commandKey = "getClusterNameForId", fallbackMethod = "defaultClusterName")
 public String getClusterNameForId(int id) {
    if (id > 0) {
        return "cluster"+id;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("command failed");
    }
 }

 public String defaultClusterName(int id, Throwable e) {
    return "No cluster - returned from fallback:" + e.getMessage();
 }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure you are setting the property, you can do that explicitly in the circuit annotation itself:

```
@HystrixCommand(commandProperties = {
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.timeout.enabled", value = "false")
})
```

I would only recommend this for debugging purposes though.

Something that jumps out to me is that Javanica uses AspectJ AOP, which I have never seen work with `new MyBean()` before. I've always have to use @Autowired with Spring or similar to allow proxying. This could well just be something that is new to me though.
If you set a breakpoint inside the `getClusterNameForId` can you see in the stack trace that its being called via reflection (which it should be AFAIK)?

Note you can remove `commandKey` as this will default to the method name. Personally I would also remove `groupKey` and let it default to the class name.

Comment: I have also tried setting @HystrixProperty but it always goes to fallback. When I place a debug point I can see that, for a single API call,  `getClusterNameForId` and fallbackMethod is called around 10-20 times.
Appears to me as a proxy issue.
Any help with AspectJ AOP javaneca example will be helpful.

Comment: The very top of the [Javanica Docs](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica) explain exactly how to configure AOP
i.e. either use the `@Bean` annotation in a Spring Configuration or add the `<bean>` tag to your xml

Comment: I am not using Spring java framework. I am trying to integrate Hystrix javanica in EJB java web project. Please let me know if I am heading in a wrong direction.
Does Javanica only work with Spring?

Comment: Javanica is implemented using AspectJ, which creates a proxy object around your commands to inject Hystrix. If you are not using AspectJ then the annotation will do nothing.
Your choices are to either use AspectJ and Javania or use Hystrix directly.